# How is $S={( x , y )∈ \mathbb R^2 : y=ax }$ closed under addition?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If the set $S$ of the equation $y = ax$, how is it a vector space, and specifically how is it closed under addition?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @crystal_math According to my textbook, I'm supposed to prove that u + v is in S. I just don't know what u or v is in this case? Is it x + y is in S?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to approach such problems is to take two points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ which satisfy the condition and see if the sum $(x_1+y_1, x_2+y_2)$ also satisfies the condition.

Clearly, $$y_1+y_2=ax_1+ax_2=a(x_1+x_2)$$

Thus $(x_1+y_1, x_2+y_2)$ satisfies the condition $y=ax$ and hence lies in the given vector space.
Hence the result follows!

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. For the commutative property then it would be that y1-kx1 + y2 - kx2= y2 - kx2 + y1-kx1 
correct?

Comment: No, if you let the points be u and v, you need to show $u+v=v+u$. That’s unrelated to $y=kx$

Comment: @ManuelLopez As Eric has already pointed out, commutativity of two elements $u,v \in V$ says $u+v=v+u$. So, you have to take two elements in $V$ and check if the previous condition holds.

Comment: So would the element u be ax1+x1 and element v be ax2+x2 ==> commutative property would be (ax1+x1) + (ax2 + x2) = (ax2 + x2) + (ax1 + x1)

Comment: @ManuelLopez Yes, that works! But you can just write it as $(x_1, y_1)$ (and mention that this point is such that it lies in the vector space) instead of $(x_1, ax_1)$ and same for $(x_2,y_2)$.

Comment: @ManuelLopez Hi! I was going through your blog/website link that you provided in the bio and read the first two articles. I loved it ! :)

Comment: @Soham Thank you so much, that means a lot!

Answer (score 1):

$$
S = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid y -ax = 0\} = \ker f
$$
where $f(x,y) = y - ax$ is a linear functional.

Kernel of a linear map is a linear subspace, check that general fact. The linearity of $f$:
$$
f(x + x’, y + y’) = y + y’ - ax - ay’ = f(x,y) + f(x’, y’),
$$
$$
f(kx, ky) = ky- kax = kf(x,y).
$$